# srcSet attribute is not working on safari

Tags: reactjs, safari, srcset

I have a navigation bar and there are several images for navigation. There are 4 of them for any one of them for scaling based on viewports.
It's as follows:

icons.ts

```js
import dashboardIcon from 'assets/icons/dashboard_icon.png'
import dashboardIcon2x from 'assets/icons/dashboard_icon@2x.png'
import dashboardIcon3x from 'assets/icons/dashboard_icon@3x.png'
import dashboardIcon4x from 'assets/icons/dashboard_icon@4x.png'

dashboardIcon: {
    src: dashboardIcon,
    srcset: `${dashboardIcon4x} 4x,${dashboardIcon3x} 3x,${dashboardIcon2x} 2x, ${dashboardIcon} 1x`,
  },
```

CustomIcon.tsx

```js
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

import { FixMeLater } from 'types'

import FilePicker from 'components/button/FilePicker'

export interface IconSourceType {
  src: string
  srcset: string
}
interface IIconProps {
  id?: string
  source: IconSourceType
  className?: string
  isFilePicker?: boolean
  getInputProps?: FixMeLater
  onClick?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
  onMouseDown?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
  onMouseUp?: (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => void
}

const CustomIcon = ({
  id = '',
  source,
  className,
  isFilePicker,
  getInputProps,
  onClick,
  onMouseDown,
  onMouseUp,
}: IIconProps) => {
  return (
    <>
      <IconWrapper
        id={id}
        onClick={onClick}
        onMouseDown={onMouseDown}
        onMouseUp={onMouseUp}
        className={className}
        src={source.src}
        srcSet={source.srcset}
        clickable={!!onClick || !!onMouseUp}
      />
      {isFilePicker && <FilePicker getInputProps={getInputProps} icon />}
    </>
  )
}

export default CustomIcon

const IconWrapper = styled.img`
  cursor: ${({ clickable }: { clickable: boolean }) => (clickable ? 'pointer' : 'unset')};
`
```

usage in NavigationBar.tsx:

```js
...
<CustomIcon source={icons.dashboardIcon} />
...
```

But this doesn't seem to work for safari even though it's working properly on any browser except safari. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you share `source.srcset` value?

Comment: @lissettdm source is ==> {
    src: dashboardIcon,
    srcset: `${dashboardIcon4x} 4x,${dashboardIcon3x} 3x,${dashboardIcon2x} 2x, ${dashboardIcon} 1x
 }

Comment: I have created this working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-gwgsjy?file=App.tsx,style.css,index.html and everything is working as expected on safari, the images change depending on the x-descriptors, let me know if this works for you, in case it works your issue is not related to the srcSet definition.

Comment: @lissettdm it didn't work...